# Random object from database with GORM

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I would like to get a random object from database only with GORM, without using database specific code.

Currently I'm using this:

```
Tag.executeQuery("from Tag order by rand()", [max: Tag.count()])
```

But I'm not satisfied with that because I'm using mysql's rand() function. Some people recommend to get all IDs, then choose a random one, and then query for the whole object, but I don't want two queries.

Is there a GORM way to do this? If not pure GORM, then maybe Hibernate solution would do the trick.

(I've seen this question here [Grails GORM to return random rows from table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374634/grails-gorm-to-return-random-rows-from-table), but it does not help :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first get a random offset, put `max:1` and then execute your query with these pagination parameters! 
(Note: you will have to do a `count()` on your table first but it isnt a very costly operation.)

Comment: I didn't have the time to test it out yet. But I'll choose it as answer :)